# NestJS & TypeORM Relations : Failed to fetch ManyToOne / OneToMany relation; user Object empty, I cannot fetch video and its corresponding uploader

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

Does no one know why it's not working? :`(
I am building a youtube clone with NestJS and VueJS. I am struggling with fetching all videos  with the the user who uploaded it. So, it's basically a ManyToOne relation, where each video can only have one "uploader", whereas an uploader can upload multiple videos.

When fetching all videos to show them on the start page, I am getting back from the API (as example 1 video object):

```
0: {title: "gfgf", id: 1, description: "gfgfgf", thumbnail: null, user: {}}
description: "gfgfgf"
id: 1
thumbnail: null
title: "gfgf"
user: {}
```

Somehow as you can see I get an empty user object back. Let me show you my code from the backend:
My videos.entity.ts

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToMany, ManyToOne, JoinColumn, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm'
import { User } from './../users/users.entity'
import { VideoLike } from 'src/videoLikes/videoLikes.entity'
import { Comment } from 'src/comments/comments.entity';

@Entity()
export class Video{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;



    @Column({length:100})
    path: string;

    @Column({length:100, nullable:true})
    thumbnail: string;
    
    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.videos, {eager:true})
    user: User;

    @Column({length:500})
    description: string;

   
    @Column({length:150})
    title: string;



  
    @OneToMany(() => VideoLike, videoLike => videoLike.user, {cascade:true})
    userWhoLiked: User[];


    @OneToMany(() => VideoLike, videoLikes => videoLikes.video,)
    videoLikes: VideoLike[];

    @OneToMany(() => Comment, (comment) => comment.video, )
    comments: Comment[];


}
```

As you can see each video belongs exactly to one user. To me this looks right. Let's look at the users.entity.ts:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToMany } from 'typeorm'
import { Video } from 'src/videos/videos.entity';
import { VideoLike } from 'src/videoLikes/videoLikes.entity';
import { Comment } from 'src/comments/comments.entity';

import { View } from 'src/views/views.entity';
import { Subscription } from 'src/subscriptions/subscriptions.entity'

@Entity()
export class User{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()

    id: string;



    @Column({length:100})
    username: string;

    @Column({length:100})
    email: string;

    @Column({length:100})
    password: string;

    @Column({length:200, default:''})
    avatar: string;
    @Column({length:200, default:''})
    cover: string;

    @Column({length:500})
    about: string;
    
    @OneToMany(() => Video, (video) => video.user)
    videos: Video[];
    @OneToMany(()=>VideoLike, (videoLike)=>videoLike.user, {onDelete: "CASCADE",onUpdate:"CASCADE", cascade: true})
    videoLikes: VideoLike[];

    @OneToMany(()=>Comment,(comment)=>comment.user, {onDelete: "CASCADE",onUpdate:"CASCADE", cascade: true})
    comments: Comment[];
    @OneToMany(()=>View,(view)=>view.user, {onDelete: "CASCADE",onUpdate:"CASCADE", cascade: true})
    views: View[];


    @OneToMany(() => Subscription, (subscription) => subscription.subscriber, {onDelete: "CASCADE",onUpdate:"CASCADE", cascade: true})
    subscribers: Subscription[]




    @OneToMany(() => Subscription, (subscription) => subscription.subscribedTo)
    subscribedTo: Subscription[]
    

}
```

Are there any mistakes? Let`s look at my services:
videos.service.ts

```
    async createVideo(videoPath: string, description: string, title: string, userId: number): Promise<Video> {
        const video = this.repo.create({ path: videoPath, description, title })
        const user = await this.userRepo.findOne(userId)
        video.user = user;
        return this.repo.save(video)
    }
```

this method correclty save the video instance into the database:

[image: video entry]

But why the hell I am not able to get the user then?
In the same file, my findAll methods looks like this:

```
    findAllVideos() {
        return  this.repo.find({ relations: ['user'] });
    }
```

Thanks a lot for your help <3

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting your `save()` call. So if you are calling your `createVideo()` and `findAllVideos()` too close enough, your code will load the video from database before its new relation is finished saving in database.

Have you `await` your `createVideo()` call ? It is not in your sampled code.

Besides, `relations:['user']` looks redudant if we follow the typeorm [documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/eager-and-lazy-relations/lazy-relations) about `eager : true` option. Either one or the other should be enough. The doc doesnt explain what happens when both are used in the same time.

Comment: Hello vincenthavinh, thx for your answer. Unfortunately, it is still not working after awaiting the save call, still getting the empty user object.  And yes, I have awaited my createVideo() call.
Awaiting my findAllVideos() does not do the job either :(

Comment: and ofc, awaitn my repo.create() call didnt work either :`(

Comment: i have got somewhat related bug, please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74302343/nest-2637-11032022-42850-pm-exceptionshandler-null-value-in-column